# How to read in a file and strip the lines, then split the values?

Tags: python-3.x, split, strip

I need to read in a file, then strip the lines of the file, then split the values on each line and finally writing out to a new file. Essentially when I split the lines, all the values will be strings, then once they have been split each line will be its own list! The code I have written is still just copying the text and pasting it to the new file without stripping or splitting values!

```
with open(data_file) as data:
    next(data)
    for line in data:
        line.rstrip
        line.split
        output.write(line)
logging.info("Successfully added lines")
```

Comment: To call functions, you need to append `()` after them. It must be `line.rstrip()` and `line.split()`. Also, can you add a small piece of example input and the output you expect from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(data_file) as data:
    next(data) #Are you sure you want this?  It essentially throws away the first line
               # of the data file
    for line in data:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split()
        output.write(line)
logging.info("Successfully added lines")
```

Comment: yes I am putting a new header into the new file! thank you it worked!

Comment: `line = line.strip().split()` could also be used to make it a little shorter. In fact, only one line is really needed inside the `for` loop: `output.write(line.strip().split())`.