# How do I remove '\n' from an imported .txt file converted into a list?

Tags: python

I am not able to remove '\n' from this list. The code is outputting sort of properly, but I can't seem to remove that. I am taking an intro to Python class in college so please keep any answers as beginner level as possible, still trying to wrap my head around this.

I'm hiding the path for my import, but this is what I have so far:

```
for line in prices:
        lines = line.rstrip('\n')
        prices = line
        prices = prices.split(',') 
    

        print(prices)
```

Output:

```
['bananas', '2.19\n']
['apples', '0.89\n']
['steak', '12.00\n']
['zucchini', '1.99\n']
['cheddar cheese', '1.99\n']
['pumpkins', '9.99\n']
['grapefruit', '0.79\n']
['milk', '4.19\n']
['fancy feast', '18.99']
```

I have tried .rstrip(), .lstrip(), .strip(), and nothing seems to be fixing it. The idea is to take a grocery receipt and separate the items and prices into two separate lists and create a dictionary with those.

Comment: You have two unrelated variables `lines` and `line`. Use `lines` if you want the version with the newline removed.

Comment: Just do it all at once: `prices = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')`

Comment: See also [How to read in a file and strip the lines, then split the values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39732465/843953)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not mutate the iterator variable (in this case `line`) and the list you are loop through (`prices`) during the loop. And you are assign the wrong value, on line 2 you strip then assign to `lines`, but in line 3 you assign `line` to `prices`.

Dont mind to create new variable to hold new value, as beginner level, i suggest you to create one for each of them:

```
for line in prices:
    stripped_line = line.rstrip('\n') # holding the value after `strip`
    splitted_line = stripped_line.split(',') # holding the value after `split`
    
    print(splitted_line)
```

Output:

```
['bananas', '2.19']
['apples', '0.89']
['steak', '12.00']
['zucchini', '1.99']
['cheddar cheese', '1.99']
['pumpkins', '9.99']
['grapefruit', '0.79']
['milk', '4.19']
['fancy feast', '18.99']
```

If you want to keep the processed value, you should create a new list, then push processed value `splitted_line` into it during the loop

```
stripped_prices = []
for line in prices:
    stripped_line = line.rstrip('\n')
    splitted_line = stripped_line.split(',')
    stripped_prices.append(splitted_line) # or append(stripped_line) if you dont want to store the splitted value
```

Or the one line pythonic way (for a bit "higher" python level):

```
stripped_prices = [line.rstrip('\n').split(',') for line in prices]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you should not mutate the iteration variable?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi It's safe to mutate the iteration variable in Python, it wont affect the loop. So it's fine to modify it during the loop if we know what we are doing. But in more complex, we might need to reuse its value many times and not mutate it will help keep the code clean and avoid bug.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you are saying. Let me clarify: Strings are immutable, so "mutate" as you have used it, really means reassign, which is a subtly different thing. It is perfectly fine to reassign the stripped value because the entire point of the operation is to remove the unwanted characters. Case-in-point: the list comprehension you've written bypasses the reassignment of the loop variable completely, and calls `split` on the result of `rstrip`. OP's question really boils down to a typo - they have failed to realize that `line` is not the same as `lines`